# Limit of an expression as $x$ tends to a particular quantity on a curve

Tags: limits, plane-curves

Say we have a curve like this:
$$ xy + y^2x^2 = x.$$
Let's call it the curve $\mathcal{C}$.

Say then that we want to find the limit of the quantity $x^2/y$ (if it exists) as $x \to - \infty$ on the curve $\mathcal{C}$. I may have designed this problem badly, but go on the assumption that we cannot solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ explicitly. (This problem is one I've made up to be similar to another problem, and in that one, that's part of the difficulty.)

How do we approach this problem? I know the formal definitions for limits, but I can't reconcile those with the fact that it must stay on the curve $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Do not modify your question after it received an answer, rather post a new question.

Comment: OK, I'll do that. I thought it was too similar to the old one, but I'll do it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every point $(x,y)$ on $C$, $(xy+\frac12)^2=x^2y^2+xy+\frac14=x+\frac14$ hence $x\geqslant-\frac14$. Thus, limits when $x\to-\infty$ are undefined on $C$.

Comment: Darn... looks like I picked a bad curve to use as an example. Thanks for the answer.